Where should my GUI Desktop Application store its program data on Linux / MacOS / Windows?
I am developing a GUI application that needs to store 'notebooks' somewhere on the disk. What are the best practices for getting this location on Linux / MacOS / Windows?
For example, my Rust code looks like this:
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
const PATH: &'static str = "~/.config/<app name>/";

#[cfg(taget_os = "windows")]
const PATH: &'static str = "some windows path?";

#[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
const PATH: &'static str = "some macos path?";

How should these paths be set?
